# CSS text position relative to background

Tags: html, css, reactjs

So I'm more of a backend than a frontend dev,
I'm having some difficulty on css.

```
    <div className="--Hero">    
    <div className="--Hero-container-text">
    <h1>this is me</h1>
    <p>hello</p>
```

note: className is because of react.

I want the text to stay relative to the background image on hero-container-text as seen below.

[image]

another example showing a different viewport.

[image]

Here's the css.

```
.--Hero {
  width: 100%;
  height: 90vh;
  background-image: url("./images/homepage/manpass.svg");
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: bottom;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.--Hero-container-text {
  position: fixed;
  left: 60%;
  top: 40%;
  padding: 0 60px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add position:relative; to your --hero and position:absolute; to your
--Hero-container-text

you set the div you want to technicaly be your canvas with a position: relative;

Avoid using percenteges for the positioning since they will most likely break ,instead use left 0  right 0 with auto margin , the code will look something like this :

```
 .--Hero {
      width: 100%;
      height: 90vh;
      background-image: url("./images/homepage/manpass.svg");
      background-size: contain;
      background-position: bottom;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      position:relative;
    }

.--Hero-container-text {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; 
  right: 0; 
  margin-left: auto; 
  margin-right: auto;
}
```